# how to Encrypt and Decrypt by AES algorithm in both python and ios xcode

Tags: python, ios, objective-c, xcode, encryption

I have the python code encryption by AES. I've already made compatible it [with android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29013414/encrypt-and-decrypt-by-aes-algorithm-in-both-python-and-android). 
I googled but i couldn't fine the same solution in IOS xcode. The big problem is to deal with options like padding, hashing key, iv size and MODE_CBC.
Do anyone can help me?

```
import base64
import hashlib
from Crypto import Random
from Crypto.Cipher import AES


class AESCipher:

    def __init__(self, key):
        self.bs = 16
        self.key = hashlib.sha256(key.encode()).digest()

    def encrypt(self, message):
        message = self._pad(message)
        iv = Random.new().read(AES.block_size)
        cipher = AES.new(self.key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
        return base64.b64encode(iv + cipher.encrypt(message)).decode('utf-8')

    def decrypt(self, enc):
        enc = base64.b64decode(enc)
        iv = enc[:AES.block_size]
        cipher = AES.new(self.key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
        return self._unpad(cipher.decrypt(enc[AES.block_size:])).decode('utf-8')

    def _pad(self, s):
        return s + (self.bs - len(s) % self.bs) * chr(self.bs - len(s) % self.bs)

    @staticmethod
    def _unpad(s):
        return s[:-ord(s[len(s)-1:])]



t = AESCipher('this is my key')
enc = t.encrypt('Hello World')
print(enc.decode('utf-8'))



t2 = AESCipher('this is my key')
print(t2.decrypt(enc))
```

Comment: you may take a look into: https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code translation service. Have you tried anything? This should be rather easy with Common Crypto.

Comment: Yes. i tried some codes. after comment of @teamnorge , i find out RNCryoto is same as PyCrypto